# Javascript Date Range With Month Overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to populate an HTML select field (#contestdate) with options based off of the current date for an event that I'm running. I am using JavaScript for the main calculation, with jQuery to add to the select field.

The date range should have the current date in the middle (highlighted red below) with 7 days of selections either side of the current date (I need to have both previous and future days as selections).

I've got the code working to display the dates, however, the days go into the negatives. The days also go past the date at the end of the month, although this is not shown. The code below should show 10/30/2015 and 10/31/2015 as the first two selections (after 'All Dates'):

[image: How it looks at the moment]

What I need is it to automatically calculate how many days are in each month, and modify the dates accordingly. I will be running the event past the end of 2015, so I also need a calculation for the years.

I can't think of a way to do this without a tonne of variables for each month and a corresponding conditional for each month.

My code is as follows:

```
// Add the available days to the dropdown for date selection (American format)
$(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    // Days 9 and under
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }

    // Months 9 and under
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }

    // Previous dates (Needs calculation for change in month / year)
    dd = dd - 8;
    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        dd = dd + 1;
        theDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        $('#contestdate').append($('<option />').val(i).html(theDate));
    }

    // Current date
    dd = dd + 1;
    theDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    $('#contestdate').append($('<option />').val('8').html(theDate.fontcolor("red")));

    // Future dates (Needs calculation for change in month / year)
    for (i = 9; i < 16; i++) {
        dd = dd + 1;
        theDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        $('#contestdate').append($('<option />').val(i).html(theDate));
    }
});
```

Please note that I need the dates in the American date format (mm/dd/yyyy), and this may alter the solution.

If anyone can let me know of (or point me in the right direction of) a way to do this painlessly, it would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: why aren't you using the `Date` object in getting the past and future dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyoWXK

Manipulating the `Date` object to get the past and future dates.

As for the option `value`, I just used the `Date` object, you can change it to whatever fits your need.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise you could do addition with getDate and getMonth! This is incredibly helpful :) I also discovered the plugin http://momentjs.com/ which may come in handy for undoubted changes requested to the project :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge great that it helped you out, and yep, momentjs is a very useful tool to use with regards to dates.